# changing linq to sql query

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I have a question regarding a Linq to SQL query.

I have following situation:

I have a search with lots of options, like location, availability, name, language etc ...

For this options i have to execute a query to retrieve the results according to options selected, how can i best do it, i cannot write a linq query like for each possibility and combination of options, but i cannot write one for all of them as it will not work, for example:

```
from p in context.people where p.location==model.location && p.availability==model.availability .... select p
```

In this case imagine availability is not selected and should not be searched for, but in this case it will be passed as false, or if location is not set and is null so it will only search for empty locations, although i just need all.

So my question is how do people handle this kind of behaviour with queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you long as you do not execute the linq query immediately you can just add where clauses to it. You can do this for example:

```
var query = from p in context.people;
if(searchOnLocation)
{
    query = query.where(p => p.location == model.location);
}
if(otherSearch)
{
    query = query.where(p => p.someOtherProperty == someotherValue);
}

var result = query.ToList();
```

As long you don't call `ToList()` on your IQueryable, the linq will not be translated into SQL. It's only in the last call, that the linq will be translated and executed against the database

Answer (score 1):

```
IQueryable<Person> query = context.people;
if(model.location != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.location == model.location);
if(model.availability != null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.availability == model.availability);
// etc
```

Basically, you can compose more and more restrictions as you go.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to implement query without if condition than you can use following syntax:

```
 var query = context.people.
                where(p => p.location == (model.location ?? p.location) 
                          && p.availability == (model.availability ?? p.availability))
               .ToList();
```